# JQuery: focus textarea after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, focus

I am using Ajax to load parts of a form. How can I focus a textarea object after the ajax request?

This is the html loaded:

```
<legend>Test</legend>
<label for="t">This is only a test</label>
<textarea></textarea>
<a href="#" class="continue">Continue</a>
```

This is the JQuery/Ajax code:

```
$.post(
    'ajax.php',
    { next:next },
    function(data){
        $('body').append($(data).hide().fadeIn('slow'));
    }
);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use .focus() trigger in your callback, after appending the html:

```
$.post(
    'ajax.php',
    { next:next },
    function(data){
        $('body').append($(data).hide().fadeIn('slow'));
        $('textarea').focus();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This snipped looks for an "autofocus" attribute in your HTML, and focuses on the given element.

```
$('[autofocus]').focus()
```

This way, if the view is loaded in Ajax, it works, and if there is no JavaScript and the view is loaded without ajax, you still get your autofocus.